# Popup after updatepanel postback is blocked by popup block

Tags: asp.net

I make a polling and want to popup the result immediately by window.open function after partial postback (updatepanel). But the popup is blocked by popup blocker. How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnPollingSubmit_OnClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePolling();
}

protected void UpdatePolling()
{
   // update the polling result
     ...
     ...

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnPollingSubmit, this.GetType(), "PollingResult", "window.open('polling-result.aspx','','width=200,height=100'), true);   

}
```

Comment: Don't use a popup but a Div positioned on top of the mainpage. Or even better and easier, use one of these "modal popups" from jQuery: http://www.blogrammierer.de/jquery-die-22-besten-modal-fenster-plugins/

Comment: @Tim, post as an answer so we can vote you up

Comment: @Greg: Ok, i thought that this is more a suggestion than an answer/solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a popup but a Div positioned on top of the mainpage. Or even better and easier: use one of these "modal popups" from jQuery: [best 22 jQuery modal popup plugins](http://www.blogrammierer.de/jquery-die-22-besten-modal-fenster-plugins/)

Comment: I agree with your initial instinct. This doesn't answer how to unblock a popup.

Comment: This doesn't work for situations like an oAuth workflow which specifies that it cannot be in an iframe, but must be in a popup window for security reasons.